# The requested address '/login' was not found on this server

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

I have created routes like this

```
    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'HomeController', 'action' => 'index']);
    $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'UserController', 'action' => 'login']);
```

http://cakephp.local/login   -> This is not working

http://cakephp.local/user/login -> This is working

Comment: @Chilarai That's not quite correct, `$routes->connect()` will connect the routes exactly as you tell the method to do. The default CakePHP application template however connects so called fallback routes via `$routes->fallback()` that connect `/controller/action` paths.

Comment: @HemanthPaidiparthi Whenever you have routing problems, check what routes exactly are connected (and include it in your question), you can do that for example with the routes shell: `bin/cake routes`. Also please make sure that you've enabled debug mode in your application, that should give you an error page that details the underlying error. Also check your application's logs, as well as your general PHP/server logs, and make sure that you include the relevant error details in your question, especially the related stacktraces, "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description!

Comment: Error: Create the class loginController below in file: src\Controller\LoginController.php

This is the exact error showing when i run http://cakephp.local/login
But i have placed the route via usercontroller
 $routes->connect('/login', ['controller' => 'UserController', 'action' => 'login']);